# .Execute not available on a type safe Entity Framework query (Include & where)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, entity-framework-5

I have a question regarding entity framework queries.

I have a query which is using the Extension methods provided by EF, so i can use type safe includes and where clause. But as the Include is with a lambda parameter it is an extension method on IQueryable that returns an IQueryable in order to chain methods like Where. Include with a string parameter is a method on ObjectQuery that returns an ObjectQuery. Execute is a method on ObjectQuery, not IQueryable so it is not available when you use IQueryable methods.

***Is there a way to call .Execute but with IQueryable?***

```
    return
    this.Storage.Customer.OfType<Preferred>()
    .Include(b  => b.Order)
    .Where(cust => cust.Id == customerId && cust.CustomerType== (int)cusType)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Thanks,

Comment: What would you like to do?

Comment: I would like to call the .Execute with a Merge Option, but this is not available when you use lambdas in your where and include as that uses an extension method. Its only available if you use strings for includes and where...

Answer (score 0):

I have found it, maybe someone can comment if this is good practice or not?

```
        var query =             
            this.Storage.Tubes.OfType<Preferred>()
                        .Include(b  => b.Order);

        return ((ObjectQuery<Preferred>)query).Execute(MergeOption.OverwriteChanges)
                                               .SingleOrDefault(cust => cust.Id == customerId && cust.CustomerType == (int)cusType);
```